# Descriptive table from rmarkdown to word using mmtable2

Tags: r, r-markdown, cpu-word

I have the following Rmd file where I want to create a table using mmtable2 to Word. However, the table has no format in Word and only showing a row of numbers. Does mmtable2 do not work in Word? Is there another package useful for creating such a table in a simple way as with mmtable2?

````
---
title: "Title"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(sf)
library(mmtable2)
library(purrr)
```

## Table


```{r, results='asis'}
df <- structure(list(tipo_violencia = c("Comunal", "Comunal", "Comunal", 
"Comunal", "Comunal", "Comunal", "Comunal", "Comunal", "Comunal", 
"Comunal", "Comunal", "Comunal", "Comunal", "Comunal", "Política", 
"Política", "Política", "Política", "Política", "Política", "Política", 
"Política", "Política", "Política", "Política", "Política", "Política", 
"Política"), Sexo = c("Hombre", "Hombre", "Hombre", "Hombre", 
"Hombre", "Hombre", "Hombre", "Mujer", "Mujer", "Mujer", "Mujer", 
"Mujer", "Mujer", "Mujer", "Hombre", "Hombre", "Hombre", "Hombre", 
"Hombre", "Hombre", "Hombre", "Mujer", "Mujer", "Mujer", "Mujer", 
"Mujer", "Mujer", "Mujer"), Ruralidad = c("ND", "ND", "No", "No", 
"Si", "Si", "Si", "ND", "ND", "No", "No", "Si", "Si", "Si", "ND", 
"ND", "No", "No", "Si", "Si", "Si", "ND", "ND", "No", "No", "Si", 
"Si", "Si"), annoh = c(2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2019, 2020, 2021, 
2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 
2019, 2020, 2021, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2019, 2020, 2021), 
    n = c(29L, 31L, 1L, 9L, 13L, 28L, 10L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L,    
    4L, 2L, 227L, 106L, 12L, 79L, 22L, 18L, 14L, 46L, 30L, 1L, 
    24L, 3L, 3L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("tbl_df", 
   "tbl", "data.frame"))

gm_table <- 
  df %>% 
  mmtable(cells = n) +
  header_left(annoh) +
  header_top(Sexo) +
  header_left_top(tipo_violencia)  +
  header_top_left(Ruralidad)

gm_table
```
````

Answer (score 0):

For now, I would try updating your version of gt using the code below:

```
remove.packages("gt")
remotes::install_github("rstudio/gt@w-tbl-exp")
```

This should produce a table with the correct layout, though the format may not carry across.

*See background on the gt version here: https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/121

Comment: do I have to add something else to the code like as_word(), gt() or something else? I updated and it works for a table using gt() but the current code I have does not work.

Comment: That seemed to work for me. You could try: apply_formats(gm_table)